# Can creating too many processes ever *negatively* affect performance?

Tags: multiprocessing

I understand that creating many processes may yield no benefit, depending on how many cores your processor has (if the tasks are CPU-bound), or depending on how many IO operations you can do simultaneously (if your tasks are IO-bound). In such cases, creating too many processes simply has no effect.

However, can creating too many processes have a *negative* effect on performance? If yes, why?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

A process that isn't active has some overhead in memory and CPU time -- not a lot, but not none. So if you have an extremely large number of processes, you will see negatives.

On a modern system, multiple processes of the same executable will share code and read-only data, but each needs its own copy of mutable data, each needs its own stack, etc. Thus, each additional process takes up some amount of memory; this means more cache pressure, and in the extreme case, more swapfile activity or outright running out of memory. There may be a hard limit to the number of processes as well.

The OS process scheduler will have more overhead working through a longer list of processes (though this probably *won't* be linearly bad; if heap-based it might be O(log n)).

Cache pressure is probably the biggest factor in practice. Assume your processes are all processing similar workloads. Some of the data they will need while processing will be shared across multiple work units, while not being known at compile time; each process will wind up having its own copy of that data. Thus two work units being handled by two processes will use up twice as much cache space for that kind of data.